# How adminer does not push anything new, but deploys new docker images?

Tags: docker

If we look at the official GitHub repository of [Adminer](https://github.com/vrana/adminer) we see that the last commit belongs to 2021.

Yet many times when we use `docker pull adminer` a new image would be downloaded.

How is it possible?

Is Adminer's official repository moved? What do I miss here?

Comment: According to its dockerhub page https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer. It says this is maintained by https://github.com/TimWolla/docker-adminer